Is my notifiable garden pump still notifiable if I add a plug?
I need to replace my Hozelock pond pump. I contacted Hozelock who have recommended a replacement which unfortunately is 240V whereas my current model is 24V and plugs into a socket in the garage.
Looking at the instruction booklet informs me that the replacement is a notifiable installation and comes without a plug. If I just pop on a 13A plug and plug into an RCD socket, is it still notifiable?

It sounds like you are in UK/Europe(13 amp socket/RCD).  If so your sockets should be 220 to 230v.  If the old pump was 24v and just plugged in, then it should have had a transformer in it/a fat wall wart.   (still notifiable)?

What does notifiable mean in this context, anyway?

@Huesmann Notifiable electrical work,

With the other comments, it will be up to you to ask the local department.  Usually the instructions over ride code, what they say is law.  Adding just a plug and having the socket already there, the local department/inspector might okay it not needing permits/notice.

Likely it comes without a plug so you would call a licensed electrician to wire it up correctly. Miswiring it potentially results in your pond being electrified, which is pretty undesirable. Call an electrician or buy a different pump that you can install yourself legally.

If you are going to submerge electrical equipment into water and it's possible to use 24V equipment, why would you want to use 240V equipment?   Can you ask Hozelock that question?  Sometimes there is a reason ... like a  2kW  sewage pump.  But a fountain pump or circulator for  a pond?   Why?

Yes, in the UK - should have said. I guess they don't supply a plug as mentioned so you don't just plug it into a non RCD protected outlet.  The new models matching the previous 1500 LPH all seem to be mains voltage. I guess I'll just call an electrician who can self-certify. Thanks for comments.

I will try to answer your question as asked.   I am not an expert on UK building regulations but some of this is a little obvious.
You should read the pump's instructions.  I have not, but it is reasonable to assume the manufacturer expects you to install, within the length of the factory power cord an electrical outlet suitable for permanent exposure to the elements.    That means perhaps the cord is long enough to reach inside your garage, in which case you can put a plug on it and be done ... there is nothing to notify because you aren't building anything.  Or perhaps you must install an outdoor waterproof electrical enclosure near the pond (within the length of the cord) and inside that, attach the pump permanently or via an outlet.   That installation might be notifiable.  It's not the use of the pump that is notifiable, but the installation of 240V electrical wiring and outlets.   What is notifiable is building work, not the device you connect to it.
If the cable is too short, you put a plug on it and use an extension cord to your garage and just leave that lying on the ground permanently .... that is probably not "notifiable" in the building regulations sense, but probably not smart at all and not what the pump maker expects.
It's hard to understand why you would use a 240V pump in a pond rather than 24V.  You can run a 24V cable from your garage to the pond, and install whatever circulators, fountains, etc you want, from wherever you want to buy them and not worry about compliance or about electrocution.   Why not choose the easy path?
